# Gulp concat vendors from NPM

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-concat

Is it possible to get vendors script (like jQuery, react…) from NPM and concat all of these into a vendors.js with Gulp using a convenient `require('jquery')` for instance?

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var jquery = require('jquery');
var lodash = require('lodash');
var react = require('react');
var reactDom = require('react-dom');
var reactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src([jquery, lodash, react, reactDom, reactBootstrap])
        .pipe(gulp.concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./local/script'));
});
```

Comment: look at `gulp-wiredep` + `gulp-concat` + `gulp-uglify` to inject/concat/minify vendor scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far, as i know, it is possible with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) .